# cmake cross-compile for raspberry pi

Tags: cmake, path, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling

I am cross-compiling a library (ORBSLAM3) on pc using /usr and /lib
from rpi4 (After using rsync). And I put them in a folder named "rootf".The prerequisite libraries have been installed before so they are now in ~/rootf/usr and ~/rootf/lib. I need to compile ORBSLAM3 using ~/rootf/ as the root.

The thing is I am not familiar with cmake so I have been struggling for a while.

The process of compiling is this:

1. using Toolchain-rpi.cmake for the CMakeLists.txt on the top level of ORBSLAM3.
2. In CMakeLists.txt, it finds pangolin by find_package(Pangolin REQUIRED)

find_package() is actually doing the right.
It successfully finds

```
/home/ethan/raspberrypi/rootfs/usr/local/lib/cmake/Pangolin/PangolinTargets.cmake
```

The CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH in this CMakeLists.txt is right, which is

```
/home/ethan/raspberrypi/rootfs/usr/local/lib;/home/ethan/raspberrypi/rootfs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
```

After I uninstall pangolin on ubuntu, I get this:

```
CMake Error at /home/ethan/raspberrypi/rootfs/usr/local/lib/cmake/Pangolin/PangolinTargets.cmake:80 (message):
  The imported target "pangolin" references the file

     "/usr/local/lib/libpangolin.so"

  but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:

  * The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
```

Since Pangolin was originally installed on board, so on board libpangolin.so is at /usr/local/lib/libpangolin.so.
I guess when I use PangolinTargets.cmake, it is doing the same thing.

I output CMAKE_SYSROOT,CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH,_IMPORT_PREFIX in PangolinTargets.cmake. It's what I expect.

```
CMAKE_SYSROOT = /home/ethan/raspberrypi/rootfs 
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH = ;/home/ethan/raspberrypi/rootfs/usr/local/lib;/home/ethan/raspberrypi/rootfs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf 
_IMPORT_PREFIX = /home/ethan/raspberrypi/rootfs/usr/local
```

Even if I add /home/ethan/raspberrypi/rootfs as prefix to the below paths, nothing changed.

```
set_target_properties(pangolin PROPERTIES
  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "/usr/include;/usr/include;/usr/include;/usr/local/include/eigen3;${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/include"
  INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES "rt;pthread;/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libGL.so;/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libGLU.so;
  INTERFACE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "/usr/include;/usr/include;/usr/include;/usr/local/include/eigen3"
)
```

Here is the content of PangolinTargets.cmake. I am not sure which parts leads to searching only /usr. Thanks all.

```
# Generated by CMake

if("${CMAKE_MAJOR_VERSION}.${CMAKE_MINOR_VERSION}" LESS 2.5)
   message(FATAL_ERROR "CMake >= 2.6.0 required")
endif()
cmake_policy(PUSH)
cmake_policy(VERSION 2.6)
#----------------------------------------------------------------
# Generated CMake target import file.
#----------------------------------------------------------------

# Commands may need to know the format version.
set(CMAKE_IMPORT_FILE_VERSION 1)

# Protect against multiple inclusion, which would fail when already imported targets are added once more.
set(_targetsDefined)
set(_targetsNotDefined)
set(_expectedTargets)
foreach(_expectedTarget pangolin)
  list(APPEND _expectedTargets ${_expectedTarget})
  if(NOT TARGET ${_expectedTarget})
    list(APPEND _targetsNotDefined ${_expectedTarget})
  endif()
  if(TARGET ${_expectedTarget})
    list(APPEND _targetsDefined ${_expectedTarget})
  endif()
endforeach()
if("${_targetsDefined}" STREQUAL "${_expectedTargets}")
  unset(_targetsDefined)
  unset(_targetsNotDefined)
  unset(_expectedTargets)
  set(CMAKE_IMPORT_FILE_VERSION)
  cmake_policy(POP)
  return()
endif()
if(NOT "${_targetsDefined}" STREQUAL "")
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Some (but not all) targets in this export set were already defined.\nTargets Defined: ${_targetsDefined}\nTargets not yet defined: ${_targetsNotDefined}\n")
endif()
unset(_targetsDefined)
unset(_targetsNotDefined)
unset(_expectedTargets)


# Compute the installation prefix relative to this file.
get_filename_component(_IMPORT_PREFIX "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}" PATH)
get_filename_component(_IMPORT_PREFIX "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}" PATH)
get_filename_component(_IMPORT_PREFIX "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}" PATH)
get_filename_component(_IMPORT_PREFIX "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}" PATH)
if(_IMPORT_PREFIX STREQUAL "/")
  set(_IMPORT_PREFIX "")
endif()

# Create imported target pangolin
add_library(pangolin SHARED IMPORTED)

set_target_properties(pangolin PROPERTIES
  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "/usr/include;/usr/include;/usr/include;/usr/local/include/eigen3;${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/include"
  INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES "rt;pthread;/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libGL.so;/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libGLU.so;/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libGLEW.so;/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so;/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libSM.so;/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libICE.so;/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libX11.so;/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libXext.so;rt;pthread;/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdc1394.so;/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpng.so;/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libz.so;/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libjpeg.so;/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libtiff.so;/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libIlmImf.so"
  INTERFACE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "/usr/include;/usr/include;/usr/include;/usr/local/include/eigen3"
)

if(CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS 2.8.12)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "This file relies on consumers using CMake 2.8.12 or greater.")
endif()

# Load information for each installed configuration.
get_filename_component(_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}" PATH)
file(GLOB CONFIG_FILES "${_DIR}/PangolinTargets-*.cmake")
foreach(f ${CONFIG_FILES})
  include(${f})
endforeach()

# Cleanup temporary variables.
set(_IMPORT_PREFIX)

# Loop over all imported files and verify that they actually exist
foreach(target ${_IMPORT_CHECK_TARGETS} )
  foreach(file ${_IMPORT_CHECK_FILES_FOR_${target}} )
    if(NOT EXISTS "${file}" )
      message(FATAL_ERROR "The imported target \"${target}\" references the file
   \"${file}\"
but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:
* The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
* An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
* The installation package was faulty and contained
   \"${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}\"
but not all the files it references.
")
    endif()
  endforeach()
  unset(_IMPORT_CHECK_FILES_FOR_${target})
endforeach()
unset(_IMPORT_CHECK_TARGETS)

# This file does not depend on other imported targets which have
# been exported from the same project but in a separate export set.

# Commands beyond this point should not need to know the version.
set(CMAKE_IMPORT_FILE_VERSION)
cmake_policy(POP)
```

Comment: Did you just copy code from https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2010-April/036459.html ? Did you read the manual? https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html It has like 10 points describing the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

> how to show the path of the file for the one that we search using find_package( )?

> CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH

> Semicolon-separated list of directories specifying installation prefixes to be searched by the find_package()...

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /home/users/rootf/usr/local/lib)
# additionalllly I also do a precaution
set(CMAKE_IGNORE_PATH / /bin /include /usr/lib /usr/local/lib)
```

You might also to manipulate with `CMAKE_FIND_USE_*_PATH` variables.

Comment: Thanks. I output CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH and it is tight.  I also edited my question a little bit. So I think the problem is clearer.